# Coupled differential equation with linear coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking to solve the following set of coupled differential equation:
\begin{align}
\frac{d A_1(\xi)}{d\xi} &= C (\xi + B) A_2(\xi), \\ \frac{d A_2(\xi)}{d\xi} &= C (\xi - B) A_1(\xi),
\end{align}
where $C$ and $B$ are constants with respect to $\xi$. It turns out that this system is easily solved when $B = 0$, but does anyone have an idea of an approach when $B \not= 0$?

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate the first equation wrt $\xi$
$$
\frac{d^2 A_1(\xi)}{d\xi^2}
= C A_2(\xi) + C (\xi + B) \frac{dA_2(\xi)}{d\xi} 
$$
and then substitute in for $A_2$
$$
\frac{d^2 A_1(\xi)}{d\xi^2}
= \frac{1 } {\xi+B} \frac{d A_1(\xi)}{d\xi}+ C (\xi + B) C (\xi - B) A_1(\xi). 
$$
You now have a single equation to solve.

Comment: Upon reaching this single DE to solve, is there a way to solve this? My guess is that it cannot be solved analytically.

Comment: Wolfram is usually a good place to start: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%27%27+-+f%27%2F(x%2Bb)-c%5E2*(x%5E2-b%5E2)f%3D0
Apparently this is a 'Sturm-Liouville Equation,' and since it has a name there's a chance someone's figured out how to solve special cases.

Comment: "Sturm-Liouville equations" is just a general name for all second-order eigenvalue problems. That's not really very helpful.